# What is the memory bandwidth in this case?

Tags: memory, simulator

I'm tweaking the configuration of an emulator to lower its bandwidth. The bandwidth I calculated by various methods is different from the paper.

```
    #define DRAM_CHANNELS 1 // default: assuming one DIMM per one channel 4GB * 1 => 4GB off-chip memory
    #define LOG2_DRAM_CHANNELS 0
    #define DRAM_RANKS 8 // 512MB * 8 ranks => 4GB per DIMM
    #define LOG2_DRAM_RANKS 3
    #define DRAM_BANKS 8 // 64MB * 8 banks => 512MB per rank
    #define LOG2_DRAM_BANKS 3
    #define DRAM_ROWS 32768 // 2KB * 32K rows => 64MB per bank
    #define LOG2_DRAM_ROWS 15
    #define DRAM_COLUMNS                                                                                                   \
        32 // 64B * 32 column chunks (Assuming 1B DRAM cell * 8 chips * 8 transactions = 64B size of column chunks) => 2KB
           // per row
    #define LOG2_DRAM_COLUMNS 5
    #define DRAM_ROW_SIZE (BLOCK_SIZE * DRAM_COLUMNS / 1024)
    
    #define DRAM_SIZE (DRAM_CHANNELS * DRAM_RANKS * DRAM_BANKS * DRAM_ROWS * DRAM_ROW_SIZE / 1024)
    #define DRAM_PAGES ((DRAM_SIZE << 10) >> 2)
#define DRAM_CHANNEL_WIDTH 32  // 32 bytes
#define tRP_DRAM_CYCLE 11
#define tRCD_DRAM_CYCLE 11
#define tCAS_DRAM_CYCLE 11
tRP  = tRP_DRAM_CYCLE  * (CPU_FREQ / DRAM_IO_FREQ); 
tRCD = tRCD_DRAM_CYCLE * (CPU_FREQ / DRAM_IO_FREQ); 
tCAS = tCAS_DRAM_CYCLE * (CPU_FREQ / DRAM_IO_FREQ); 
DRAM_MTPS = 1600;  //1600MT/s
#define CPU_FREQ 4000  //4GHZ
#define DRAM_IO_FREQ 800 //0.8GHZ
DRAM_MTPS = 1600;
```

What is the memory bandwidth in this configuration? It's called 37.5GB/s in the paper, but I can't get the same result. The paper's authors did not respond to emails.

First:

The `IO frequency` is `0.8GHZ`, `DRAM_CHANNEL_WIDTH` is `32`, there are `8` `RANKs` in total, so the memory bandwidth is `IO frequency*DRAM_CHANNEL_WIDTH *RANK_number` =   `0.8*32*8/8 =25.6GB/s`
Is that right?

second
DRAM_MTPS = 1600,
memory bandwidth = DRAM_MTPS * data_width/8 = `1600*32*8/8/1024 = 50GB/s`
How to calculate is right?